# How to propert kill ASP.NET Core application to restart docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a simple ASP.NET Core Web API application that runs in docker container.

This app should process HTTP requests and consume events from Kafka. So, in Startup.Configure method I run dedicated thread with infinity loop to consume events.

```
public void Consume()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var eventMsg = _consumer.Consume();
                await Handle(eventMsg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _consumer.Close();
                    // log error
            throw;
        }
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

Then in Startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();

            var consumer = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<KafkaConsumer>();
            consumer.Consume();
        }
```

But when error occurs in loop I need to restart container with application. In simple application when I add `throw;` then it generate unhandled exception, close application and in a result container will be restarted. But in this case `throw;` didn't help, because it throw in background thread and I'm not waiting for result. I'm not waiting for result, because when I add

```
await consumer.Consume();
```

it stops all application and WebAPI not run.

How to handle this in proper way? If short, I need throw exception in background thread then close app to automatically restart container. I can't add `Application.Exit` to `Consume` method, because it is  a library, and I can't change code.

Is there any other way to kill app from background thread?

Please let me know if I need to add more info before closing it.

Comment: That's not the proper way to run a background processing event in an ASP.NET Core App. Anyways - why would you want to? The whole point of Docker is that it's super easy to run multiple services. Extract all that background logic out, shove it into a console app, and run it in its own container.

Comment: Yeah, but it consume event and update cache, which read by controllers

Comment: Store the cache elsewhere in a common location where both this background service and your web app can read it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This app should process HTTP requests and consume events from Kafka. So, in Startup.Configure method I run dedicated thread with infinity loop to consume events.

The [proper way to run a background service on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services) is to use Hosted Services. So your code would look like this:

```
public class KafkaConsumer : BackgroundService
{
  public KafkaConsumer()
  {
    _consumer = ...;
  }

  protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) => Task.Run(async () => 
  {
    try
    {
      while (true)
      {
        var eventMsg = _consumer.Consume();
        await Handle(eventMsg);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      _consumer.Close();
      ... // log error
      throw;
    }
  });
}
```

and it's [registered in your startup class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#the-configureservices-method) like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddHostedService<KafkaConsumer>();
}
```

> But when error occurs in loop I need to restart container with application.

To do this, inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` and call `StopApplication`:

```
public class KafkaConsumer : BackgroundService
{
  private IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

  public KafkaConsumer(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
  {
    _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    _consumer = ...;
  }

  protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) => Task.Run(async () => 
  {
    try
    {
      while (true)
      {
        var eventMsg = _consumer.Consume();
        await Handle(eventMsg);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      _consumer.Close();
      ... // log error
      _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
      throw;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Stephen Cleary could you please elaborate in more details, how calling `StopApplication` can restart container? Also, as I know `StopApplication`  will trigger delegates registered on ApplicationStopping (can be used for graceful shutdown).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: `StopApplication` will exit the current process, which will stop the container. The container must be restarted by some external mechanism, i.e., a container orchestrator.

Comment: Ok, caught it.  In that case do we need rethrow after `StopApplication` and more over just a rethrow will terminate (abnormal) as well so container will stop anyway.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: You don't have to rethrow; that's just a stylistic preference in this case.